# How to use SUBSTITUTE() for a range of values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say that there are multiple values like such:

```
Address
123 Fake Street, Philadelphia, pa
456 Real Street, Houston, tx
789 Soho Street, New York, ny
```

Originally, I thought I could create a lookup table to search for "pa", "tx", and "ny" so that they would get upper'd: "PA", "TX", "NY".

Ideally, I want to write a function that would have all of the upper values in a new column. Originally, something like this:

```
=substitute(O33,Q31:Q35,R31:R35)
```

with `Q31:Q35` being the range of lower states, and `R31:R35` being the upper states. However, that didn't work out the way I wanted. Is there a way to do the replacement of lower case states without hard coding? I thought a lookup table would work, but it didn't.

I want the end result to be something like this:

```
Address                                     New Address
123 Fake Street, Philadelphia, pa           123 Fake Street, Philadelphia, PA
456 Real Street, Houston, tx                456 Real Street, Houston, TX
789 Soho Street, New York, ny               789 Soho Street, New York, NY
```

Without doing this for every row of New Address:

```
substitute(A2, "pa", "PA")
substitute(A3, "tx", "TX")
substitute(A4, "ny", "NY")
```

Comment: I tried your formula, it worked fine, What was your problem with this formula?

Answer (score 1):

A lookup table should work, try using a vlookup. You want to take the 2 right characters from the address and use that as the lookup value to return the upper case version, roughly like this (assume address in A1):

```
new value = left(A1, len(A1)-2) & vlookup(right(A1, 2), Q31:R35, 2, false)
```

also if there is no complex mapping i.e. you are always just capitalizing the last 2 characters you could do this:

```
new value = left(A1, len(A1)-2) & upper(right(A1, 2))
```

Comment: Does it look to be possible to only use SUBSTITUTE() for this problem?

Comment: you could probably find a way, I don't usually look for difficult solutions to problems when I have easy ones at hand ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try an array formula.

in A2 until A4 you have your addresses

```
123 Fake Street, Philadelphia, pa
456 Real Street, Houston, tx
789 Soho Street, New York, ny
```

in Q31:Q33 and R31:R33 you have :

```
pa  PA
tx  TX
ny  NY
```

In E2, enter this formula :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2:A4;Q31:Q33;R31:R33)
```

In the formula bar type CTRL SHIFT and ENTER.
You will see {} in the formula like this :

```
{=SUBSTITUTE(A2:A4;$Q$31:$Q$33;$R$31:$R$33)}
```

Then copy the formula in E3 and E4.

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to replace the last two characters with their uppercase counterparts then you could use this formula:

=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&UPPER(RIGHT(A1,2))

It trims the text to exclude the right two characters while creating a second text string of the right two where it capitalizes them. Then it concatenates the two strings into one.

The trouble with using SUBSTITUTE is that it will replace all occurrences of the last two characters with their uppercase versions. So "123 Funny Street, New York, ny" would become "123 FunNY Street, New York, NY".